# How can I run different test configurations in Angular 7

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

By default we have got .spec.ts as our test files.

And we have got following config for same.

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": ["node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "codeCoverage": true
      }
    }
```

However what If I have two sets of test files, lets say **spec.ts and spec1.ts.**

Can I run a command ng test to run all the .spec files and another command to run all *.spec1 files.

What changes I should have in the angular.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got something working that may work for you.

First, I created a copy of the *tsconfig.spec.json* file, and named it *tsconfig.spec1.json*, I suppose you can name it whatever you like. This is what the contents of the file are:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
        "types": [
        "jasmine",
        "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "test.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*.spec1.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Notice the `**/*.spec1.ts` glob in the `includes` section of the file.

Then, from the command prompt, I ran the following:

```
ng t --include=**/*.spec1.ts --tsConfig=./src/tsconfig.spec1.json
```

I created a couple of *spec1.ts* files by copying some other spec files I had, and renamed them. The command above only ran the tests in those files. Seems to work.

Give it a shot. Not too much work really.

You can add the following to the `scripts` section of the *package.json*:

```
"test1": "ng t --include=**/*.spec1.ts --tsConfig=./src/tsconfig.spec1.json",
```

Then run `npm run test1` to run just the *spec1* tests.

I tried to run the command above without the `--include=./**/*.spec1.ts` because it is in the new *tsconfig* file I created, but it didn't like that.

I also tried creating a copy of the *test.ts*, and changing the `files` to include `test1.ts`, then running `ng t --tsConfig=./src/tsconfig.spec1.json`, no go.

Comment: Thank you, For the renamed files I get this error, ```Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha```

Comment: Are you using jest for testing? This answer is based on using karma and jasmine; out of the box Angular CLI test setup.

Comment: I have to rename the config file as well . Thanks working now